# Parse value of a specific element in a random position of a JSON file

Tags: text-processing, json

I would like to match the value after `"sid"` for `VALUE1` (=`789069`)
The problem is that the order of the lines is random.

```
[{"cid":"PWER","data":[{"VALUE1":0}],"sid":"789069","units":"kWm","age":586667},
{"cid":"PWER","data":[{"VALUE2":809}],"sid":"788325","units":"kWm","age":11},
{"cid":"PWER_SUB","data":[{"VALUE3":278}],"sid":"789540","units":null,"age":1},
{"cid":"PWER_SUB","data":[{"VALUE4":319}],"sid":"789093","units":null,"age":38},
{"cid":"PWER_SUB","data":[{"VALUE5":0}],"sid":"789069","units":null,"age":4}
```

Any ideas how to match it?

Comment: is that json? you should use a tool the natively understands json

Comment: This can be done, fairly easily, with python's json API , but it looks like this is just an incomplete portion of the file. Would it be possible  to provide a full text to work with ?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the missing `]` is inserted at the end, this is a JSON document and should be parsed with a JSON parser such as [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ jq -r '.[] | select(.data[0].VALUE1) | .sid' data.json
789069
```

This will take the array of JSON objects and select the object that has a key called `VALUE1` in the first element of the `data` array entry. It will then extract the value of the `sid` entry from that object.

The `-r` option to `jq` is for "raw output". Without it we would have received a double-quoted value.

Comment: Unfortunately jq does not return anything :(

# jq -r '.[] | select(.data[0].VALUE1) | .sid' testfile
#

Comment: @amprantino With the missing `]` inserted in the data that you provided, this is the output that I get. If your JSON document has further structure that invalidates this `jq` query, then the query needs to be changed, obviously.

Comment: I am just using the data above plus a "]" at the end.

Comment: @amprantino What version of `jq` are you using? My version seems to be 1.5.

Comment: Hmmm. jq --version does not show output. I am using debian 32bit (test enviroment) show probably there is an issue with the jq package

Answer (score 1):

Grep is a good tool for this kind of problems
`grep -oP '"sid":"\d+"' file`
. Is this what you are looking for?

**UPDATE**: IT is not!!! ( Sorry: I did not understood the intial question. )

second version: using a json tool named `json`:

```
cat a.json | json -c '"VALUE1" in this.data[0]' | json -a sid
```

or

```
cat a.json | json -c '"VALUE1" in this.data[0]' -a sid
```

- `json -c predicate`  - filters the elements (filter)
- `json -a expression`  - applies expression to all the elements (map)

documentation in: http://trentm.com/json/. If not installed:

```
install node
and sudo npm install -g json
```

Answer (score 0):

In `awk` if you want to match the whole record then you can use:

```
awk '{if($0~/789069/){print $0}}' file
```

In this code, `awk` will check if a line include the value `789069` then it will print it as is and ignore other lines.

Output:

```
[{"cid":"PWER","data":[{"VALUE1":0}],"sid":"789069","units":"kWm","age":586667},
{"cid":"PWER_SUB","data":[{"VALUE5":0}],"sid":"789069","units":null,"age":4}
```